# Make large Mysqli insert more efficient

Tags: php, mysql, performance, mysqli

I have a several big forms that need to be inserted into a database.

I am currently doing it like this

```
$stmt = $memberMysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO questionnairebespokeexerciseplan(userid,date,naturalbodytype,framesizewrist,framesizeelbow,fitnessgoals,workpattern,sleephours,runningbarriers,workcommute,workdistance,smoke,biomechanicalissues,limitingillness,reletivesheartproblems,birthlast12months,recurringinjuries,regularmedication,pregnant,anythingelsehealth,gymmember,runoutdoors,wouldyouliketorunoutdoors,homeequipments,whattypeequipment,exercisetime,heartratemonitor,restingheartrate,actualheartrate,maxheartrate,heartratesteadyrun,heartratebreathless,trainingshoes,preferredexercisetype,exerciseclasses,classdays,bike,bikemodel,runlunchtimebeforework,clubmember,clubschedule,personaltraining,otherheartrate,foottype) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss',
                                                $_POST['userid'],
                                        $date,
                                        $_POST['naturalbodytype'],
                                        $_POST['framesizewrist'],
                                        $_POST['framesizeelbow'],
                                        $_POST['fitnessgoals'],
                                        $_POST['workpattern'],
                                        $_POST['sleep'],
                                        $_POST['runbarriers'],
                                        $_POST['workcommute'],
                                        $_POST['workmiles'],
                                        $_POST['smoke'],
                                        $_POST['biomechanical'],
                                        $_POST['illnesses'],
                                        $_POST['heartcondition'],
                                        $_POST['givenbirth'],
                                        $_POST['injuries'],
                                        $_POST['medication'],
                                        $_POST['pregnant'],
                                        $_POST['anythingelse'],
                                        $_POST['gymmember'],
                                        $_POST['runoutdoors'],
                                        $_POST['liketorunoutside'],
                                        $_POST['homeequipment'],
                                        $_POST['equipment'],
                                        $_POST['besttime'],
                                        $_POST['heartratemonitor'],
                                        $_POST['restingheartrate'],
                                        $_POST['actualheartrate'],
                                        $_POST['actualmaxheartrate'],
                                        $_POST['heartratesteadyrun'],
                                        $_POST['heartratebreathless'],
                                        $_POST['trainingshoes'],
                                        $_POST['preferredexersize'],
                                        $_POST['classes'],
                                        $_POST['classdays'],
                                        $_POST['bike'],
                                        $_POST['whatbike'],
                                        $_POST['beforeworklunchtime'],
                                        $_POST['clubmember'],
                                        $_POST['clubschedule'],
                                        $_POST['personaltrainer'],
                                        $_POST['otherheartrate'],
                                        $_POST['foottype']
                                        );
```

I was just thinking if there was a better/quicker way of doing this?

As currently it takes a bit of time to create this and debugging it when things are not right is as equally time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write yourself a script that automates the generation of this statement. **Make sure you keep field names consistent** (on your forms and in the DB), and then maybe a piece of code like this could work for you:

```
// ADD ALL YOUR FIELDS TO THIS ARRAY. 
// THIS SHOULD BE THE ONLY PART OF THE CODE 
// WHICH YOU WILL HAVE TO MAINTAIN.

$fields = array(
'userid',
'date',
'naturalbodytype',
'framesizewrist' //etc. add all your fields
);

//you may have to adjust some fields manually:

$_POST['date'] = $date;


//HERE IS WHERE THE AUTOMATED PART STARTS
//YOU WONT EVER HAVE TO TOUCH THIS PART

//writing all fields for the query
$all_fields = implode(', ' $fields); 

//writing the correct number of questionmarks    
$questionmarks = str_repeat('?, ' count($fields)-1).'?';

//generate your statement
$stmt = $memberMysqli->prepare(
"INSERT INTO questionnairebespokeexerciseplan
 ( {$all_fields} ) 
 VALUES 
 ( {$questionmarks} )");

//write the correct amount of 's' characters for parameter types
$parameter_types = str_repeat('s' count($fields));


//generate the code which will write the parameters

$all_fields_to_bind=array();

foreach($fields as $field)
{
    $all_fields_to_bind[] = "\$_POST['". $field. "']";
}

//generate the code to be evaluated
$eval_statement = '$stmt->bind_param($parameter_types,'.implode(', ', $all_fields_to_bind).');';

//evaluate (meaning execute) your dynamically generated code
eval($eval_statement);
```

**I did not test this**, there may still be some syntax errors. Also I have no idea how secure it is! But it should work, as I am using something similar for a SELECT statement.

Comment: As seen on the PHP manual with 83% likes: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php#107034

Answer (score -1):

[SafeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) can make your code 3 times shorter. Though to list all the allowed fields is essential.

```
$allowed = explode(",","userid,date,naturalbodytype,framesizewrist,framesizeelbow,fitnessgoals,workpattern,sleephours,runningbarriers,workcommute,workdistance,smoke,biomechanicalissues,limitingillness,reletivesheartproblems,birthlast12months,recurringinjuries,regularmedication,pregnant,anythingelsehealth,gymmember,runoutdoors,wouldyouliketorunoutdoors,homeequipments,whattypeequipment,exercisetime,heartratemonitor,restingheartrate,actualheartrate,maxheartrate,heartratesteadyrun,heartratebreathless,trainingshoes,preferredexercisetype,exerciseclasses,classdays,bike,bikemodel,runlunchtimebeforework,clubmember,clubschedule,personaltraining,otherheartrate,foottype");

$data = $db->filterArray($_POST,$allowed);
$sql = "INSERT INTO questionnairebespokeexerciseplan SET ?u";
$db->query($sql, $data);
```